# Onclick JavaScript not working properly in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Please excuse my ignorance I am not very familiar with JavaScript and have been tasked with repairing a bug by a developer no longer at the company.

The `onclick` works perfectly in FireFox, however in IE 7&8 (the only ones we test for), it appears to run through the `onclick` functions properly, then instead of the data being submitted to the form URL in `goStep3()`, it runs through every `onclick` on the page, with `href="#"` then finally submits with incorrect information as the variable has been overwritten 50 times.

```
<a href="#" onclick="trackSponsor(62, 64265); goStep3(1896, 64265, 0); return false;">view</a>
```

**EDIT:**
When I run `trackSponsor(62, 64265); goStep3(1896, 64265, 0); return false;` in the Developer Tools in IE8 I get an error of returning false outside of a function....removing that it works just fine.

Is the line that I believe is causing the problems?

`trackSponsor()` is working properly and returns `false`

`goStep3()` is quite a large function however it works by retrieving values from 4 other functions within, assigning the values to a URL within `theAction`

It completes the function by **EDIT:**

```
var yr = $("#find-yr").attr('value');
var me = $("#find-me").attr('value');
var mo = $("#find-mo").attr('value');
var keywords = $("#find-keywords").attr('value');
var theAction = PATH_BASE+'find/step3/'+p_term+'/'+p_id+'/'+p_l_id+'/';

document.forms['FindForm'].action = theAction;
document.FindForm.submit(); 
return true;
```

I have tried returning false from this function, as well as changing the `document.FindForm.submit()` to the 'correct' syntax of `document.forms['FindForm'].submit()` and it still does not submit until running through all of the other `onclick` s on the page.

Thanks in advance!

Notes:

jQuery is being used as well.

Javascript is not throwing any errors.

This works fine in FireFox

I can see it going through all of the other functions in the other `onclick`s using Developer Tools and stepping through the page it does not submit the results of `goStep3` until it has gone through all of the other `onclick` functions on the page.

Comment: If you reduce your goStep3 function down to just the form submission, what happens?

Comment: edited to include that information. It is almost like the 'onclick' is somehow triggering all of the 'onclick's on the whole page...

Comment: Can you post more of the code from the goStep3() function. I have done some testing based on the code that you have presented here and I cannot reproduce your results. Are you using any javascript frameworks such as jQuery or Prototype?

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors occurring? Ensure you have error reporting on. Difficult to say what's happening without any of the rest of `goStep3`. (The accessibility/usability of this looks horrible btw.)

Comment: How are you determining that "and it still does not submit until running through all of the other 'onclick' s on the page."? It is hard for us to understand exactly what is happening here.

Comment: ok more goStep3() added, and I also added a notes section to help answer the other questions.

Comment: i see alot of Jquery being used with attribute selectors, so plz check the code against those..

Comment: I just can't see it going through all other onclicks on the page by accident.  It would have to be an explicit call...  if you put an alert in the onclick function of one other link... do you get an alert?

Comment: @Zoidberg: they are all dynamically generated using PHP, I can't edit one without editing all of them. 
@Madi D: alright, that would make sense if it didn't work at all, however it works when you enter just the functions into the console in IE8 Developer Tool

Comment: i noticed ur unfamiliar with Javascript.. so in-case u didnt know, a jQuery selector, will select all tags matching a certain "selector-filter" and perform a certain action on them... so  if there is a selector that selects all A tags with a href attribute (or maybe another common attribute between them..) then that would be the cause of your problem ..

Comment: @Madi D: alright this sounds like another good possibility...Could this cause it to not work in IE, but still work perfectly in Firefox?

Comment: I think IE is multi-threaded when it comes to invoking events... firefox is not... I have had similar issues to this with IE but not firefox... I think Madi D is correct on this one... he should put it in as an answer so I can upvote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was called because of how IE uses the bubble! Thanks all for your help, I have included the code solution to be placed in goStep3().

```
    var browserName = navigator.appName;
if (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"posting my earlier comment as an answer"

I see a lot of jQuery being used with attribute selectors, so plz check the code against those.

**EDIT:**

I noticed ur unfamiliar with JavaScript... so in-case u didnt know, a jQuery selector, will select all tags matching a certain "selector-filter" and perform a certain action on them... so if there is a selector that selects all A tags with a `href` attribute (or maybe another common attribute between them...) then that would be the cause of your problem.

**EDIT: -after you posted your answer -**

glad you found an answer...

though it is alittle werid,
cause according to your question it goes through **"every element with href="#"**  ...

However According to  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533022%28VS.85%29.aspx), Event bubbling simply passes these unhandled events to the parent element for handling. not through **"similar"** tags :)

oh well..nothing is logical when it comes to IE

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing "return false;" from the onClick event since it really isn't doing anything.

Comment: It's stopping the link to `#` being followed, making the page jump and potentially stopping the navigation. It *must* be left in.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense now that I think about it. The answer below referencing "javascript:void(0)" would solve that.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
 href="#"
```

with

```
 href='javascript:void(0)' .
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't make any effect either.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure where things are going wrong, but I discourage using a form's `name` attribute to reference it like you have done here:

```
document.forms['FindForm'].action = theAction;
document.FindForm.submit();
```

Why not try the following jQuery:

```
$("form:FindForm").action = theAction;
$("form:FindForm").trigger("submit");
```

You should also check that `$("form:FindForm")` is indeed referencing the desired form element.

Comment: Sorry I did not write the code, I have just been tasked with attempting to fix.
Your method is returning 'Object Expected' in the query-1.2.3 file and 'Object doesn't support this property or method' in goStep3()

Comment: The form element can't be found. You are receiving this error because you can't reach `.action` on a missing object. Consider giving the form element an `id` attribute and referencing it in that manner.

Comment: Ok this line document.FindForm.submit(); is used multiple places and works. In Fact, the form is <form name="FindForm" id="search_form" action="/find/step2" method="post">

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you reference it using `$("#search_form")` (as opposed to `$("form:FindForm")`)?

Comment: it submits to itself - as it is currently sitting on /find/step2